# Consumer/producer program got stuck

Tags: c

Below is the code of an example consumer/producer model:

```
int buffer[MAX];
int fill_ptr = 0;
int use_ptr = 0;
int count = 3;

void put(int value) {
    buffer[fill_ptr] = value;
    fill_ptr = (fill_ptr + 1) % MAX;
    count++;
}

int get() {
    int tmp = buffer[use_ptr];
    use_ptr = (use_ptr + 1) % MAX;
    count--;
    return tmp;
}

cond_t empty, fill;
mutex_t mutex;
void *producer(void *arg) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); // p1
        while (count == MAX) // p2
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex); // p3
        put(i);// p4
        pthread_cond_signal(&fill); // p5
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // p6
    }
}


void* consumer(void *arg) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); // c1
        while (count == 0) // c2
            pthread_cond_wait(&fill, &mutex); // c3
        int tmp = get(); // c4
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty); // c5
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // c6
        printf("%d\n", tmp);
    }
}
```

However, I think there is a problem in here. Assume MAX=3, and initially the buffer is full (count = 3), then the consumer can execute a `get()` and signal to the producer.  After the producer receives a signal, it wakes up and begins to execute `put()` in buffer[0] with the mutex held.

Assume the producer just got stuck in `put()`; then the consumer cannot continue either (because the mutex is held by producer) even though there are 2 resources left.

Is my understanding correct? If so, that's unfair because there are 2 resources left which can be consumed.

Comment: *Assume the producer just got stuck in put()* "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" -- "Don't do this, then". Don't dereference a null pointer. Don't cause buffer overflows. Don't allow a thread holding a mutex to get stuck.

Comment: Be cautious using the term 'signal' here.  It has a specific meaning in POSIX systems unrelated to what happens as you modify conditions and mutexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Both yes and no.

Yes, it is correct that the `consumer`will be stuck if the `producer` calls `put` and `put` gets stuck (e.g. by entering a endless loop).

However, you can't assume that `there are 2 resources left`. The `pthread_cond_signal`does not promise the `producer` executes before the `consumer` have read all 3 three elements. All you can know is that the `consumer` read at least one element but maybe it read 2 or even 3 before the producer executes.

> If so, that's unfair ....

No, it is not unfair. It is exactly what a mutex is for, i.e. making sure that only one thread has access to the shared resource.

Therefore it is important to make sure that a thread holding a mutex **will not** get stuck! That is your responsibility as a programmer.

Note: In your case there is nothing inside put that can cause the thread to be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> Assume the producer just got stuck in put(); then the consumer cannot continue either (because the mutex is held by producer) even though there are 2 resources left.

You must never do something that can get stuck while you hold the mutex, and your code does not.